# String array to object array with key-value pair inside the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, logparser

I want to construct an object array with key-value pair from a string array.

the string array format:

`['<ISO Date> - <Log Level> - {"user_id: "<UUID>", "details": "<message event/action description>", "err": "<Optionall, error description>"}']`

the object array format:

`[{"timestamp": <Epoch Unix Timestamp>, "loglevel": "<loglevel>", "transactionId: "<UUID>", "err": "<Error message>" }]`

```
stringArray = [
   "2021-08-09T02:12:51.259Z - error - {\"user_id\":\"1234-1111\",\"details\":\"Cannot find user orders list\",\"code\": 404,\"err\":\"Not found\"}",
   "2022-08-09T02:12:51.275Z - error - {\"user_id\":\"1111-1234\",\"details\":\"Cannot find user orders list\",\"code\":404,\"err\":\"Cannot find user orders list"}"
];

objectArray = [
   {
      "timestamp":1628475171259,
      "loglevel":"error",
      "userId":"1234-1111",
      "err":"Not found"
   },
   {
      "timestamp":1660011171275,
      "loglevel":"error",
      "userId":"1111-1234",
      "err":"Cannot find user orders list"
   }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You may deconstruct each line as `"timestamp" - "logLevel" - "jsonStringified"`

The later can be `JSON.parse`d to retrieve the object

Note that maybe you should ensure that **every** line holds the format. Otherwise you would have errors to handle (what if no jsonStringified, what is someone else outputted some random lines, etc)

```js
stringArray = [
   "2021-08-09T02:12:51.259Z - error - {\"transactionId\":\"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e978\",\"details\":\"Cannot find user orders list\",\"code\": 404,\"err\":\"Not found\"}",
   "2022-08-09T02:12:51.275Z - error - {\"transactionId\":\"9abc55b2-807b-4361-9dbe-aa88b1b2e978\",\"details\":\"Cannot find user orders list\",\"code\":404,\"err\":\"Cannot find user orders list\"}"
];
const tsCapture = '(.{'+"2022-08-09T02:12:51.275Z".length+'})'
const levelCapture = '(error|warning|debug)'
const stringCapture = '(.+)'
const reg = new RegExp('^'+tsCapture + ' - ' + (levelCapture) + ' - ' + stringCapture+'$')

const parsed = stringArray.map(line => {
  const [_, timestamp, logLevel, str] = line.match(reg)
  return {timestamp, logLevel, ...JSON.parse(str)}
})

console.log({ parsed })
```

Comment: hey man @grodzi, would you please explain what you did here line by line please?

Comment: I think you understand that I am iterating each line of stringArray
for a given line. Then I match each interesting portion (namely timestamp, logLevel and the JSON parsable part (named str).
To match those part, I have written the associated RegExp (tsCapture, levelCapture, stringCapture).
tsCapture read n chars (where n is the number of chars for an ISOString date), levelCapture capture one of error, warning or debug, then stringCapture captures the "rest" part of the line

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can do this by splitting using tokens

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for(int i=0;i<stringArray.length; i++) {
            String string = stringArray[i];
            String[] stringSplit = string.split(" - ");
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put("timestamp", stringSplit[0]);
            object.put("loglevel", stringSplit[1]);
            String[] transtactionDetailSplit = stringSplit[2].split(":|,");
            object.put("transactionId", transtactionDetailSplit[1]);
            object.put("err", transtactionDetailSplit[7]);
            jsonArray.add(object);
        }
        System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

Kindly add null check wherever needed